# How can I deploy only the pom file to my snapshot repository in Maven?

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

I would like to be able to deploy only the POM artifact (file) without the main artifact (JAR, WAR, etc), when running `mvn deploy` and version is a SNAPSHOT version.

**Why?**

We several developers working on multiple Maven projects. We have a Hudson server with a job per Maven project and version (e.g. foo-1.2, foo-1.3). Each job builds the project and deploys it to a Nexus server (upon success). Maven projects under development are marked as such by using -SNAPSHOT postfix in the version. For example: 1.2-SNAPSHOT, 1.3-SNAPSHOT.

Here's a sample scenario how a developer work is damaged due to this architecture.

Assume two Maven projects: foo-core and foo-webapp, both at version 1.2-SNAPSHOT.

- Developer A is working on foo-core, made several changes and compiled it.
- Developer A continues to work, but on foo-webapp.
- Developer B started working and changing foo-core. It commits his work and pushes it to the SCM.
- Hudson is triggered by SCM; Builds foo-core and deploys it to the snapshot repository in Nexus.
- Developer A is running `mvn install` on foo-webapp. Maven is checking with Nexus, and finds that there is a newer version of foo-core in Nexus. It downloads it (filled with developer B changes) and than it fails compilation, since the changes made by developer A are not in the jar located in the local repository. The download overrides the file installed there by developer A.

**Existing Solutions**

I looked into maven-deploy-plugin, but this plugin deploys all artifacts attached to the project. If they had a way to configure which artifacts to deploy, it would have been great.

**Question**: Is there any way to solve this without resorting to writing my own deploy plugin, based on maven-deploy-plugin?

Answer (score 24):

Basically to the `-Dfile` parameter, instead of the artifact, pass the `pom.xml`. Run the command and yay! `mvn deploy` won't give you any issues now. Here's a sample deploy command :

```
$ mvn deploy:deploy-file -DpomFile=pom.xml -Dfile=./pom.xml -DgroupId=my.group.id -DartifactId=artifact-id -DrepositoryId=bigdata-upload-snapshots -Durl=http://maven.mymaven.com/content/repositories/snapshots/
```

A prerequisite for this is that the repository be added in your settings.xml

[Edit]: I have supplied the parameters `-DgroupId` and `-DartifactId` of the project in the sample deploy command  but they're not required (refer to Zac's comment below)

Comment: If you're using `-DpomFile=` you don't need to use groupId and artifactId; those will be inferred from the pom.

Answer (score 2):

I never heard of such a possibility and also would be very astonished if that would be possible. As the pom and the resulting artifact are some kind of unit it would make no scence (to me) to deploy only parts of them.

Nevertheless you should consider to make a separate pom project which specified dependencies and plugins you might want to use on your JAR/WAR projects like this:

```
<groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>my-pom</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

and then inherit that pom project by your JAR/WAR projects like this:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-pom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

This is called [project inheritance](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance). You can change and deploy your pom project independent of the "child" artifacts.

**EDIT** after reading motivation:

As I understand you want to prevent maven to resolve SNAPSHOT artifacts from a repository (so that local version won't be overwritten). Have you ever tried to use the mvn -nsu option (see `mvn -help`)?

```
-nsu,--no-snapshot-updates             Suppress SNAPSHOT updates
```

I never tried it but found this reported [issue](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5064). Nevertheless I would give it a try (as the issue is not commented yet).

Comment: I've edited my question and added the motivation for the request to clarify my question better.

Comment: I agree with @FrVaBe, and do not think what you ask can be done, nor do I think it is the best solution to your situation anyway. The `-nsu` and `-o` (offline) flags would be useful for Developer A to avoid the issue. However, if Developer A is building the code from the toplevel of a multi-module project, it should not be necessary, since his local version of foo-core will take precedence over the new one deployed by Hudson. Lastly, by default Maven looks for snapshot updates only once every 24 hours, so this situation would occur at most once per day per environment.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for deploying a **pom file only** (e.g next to an existing jar):
(**Note:** you need to **specify packaging also**, otherwise it will be uploaded as an `.xml` file which is not what you want.)

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file \
-Dfile=pom.xml \
-Dpackaging=pom \
-DgroupId=com.mycompany.package \
-DartifactId=my-artifact \
-Dversion=2.0.1 \
-DrepositoryId=serverIdFromSettingsXMLForCredentials \
-Durl=http://repositoryserver/myrepo/
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer these folks were asking for. My situation was I wanted to deploy only the parent pom. I'm using the `spring-boot-thin-layout` in a child module. This requires the parent module be deployed into artifactory. I added the following into my project. It enables skipping of `install` and/or `deploy` phase.

In my parent pom:

```
<properties>
    <disable.install>true</disable.install>
    <disable.deploy>true</disable.deploy>
    <enable.deployAtEnd>true</enable.deployAtEnd>
</properties>

<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>deploy-parent</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <disable.install>true</disable.install>
            <disable.deploy>true</disable.deploy>
            <deployAtEnd>${enable.deployAtEnd}</deployAtEnd>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>${project.version}</finalName>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

And the in my child pom(s) or any module you don't want deployed with parent:

```
<properties>
    <maven.install.skip>${disable.install}</maven.install.skip>
    <maven.deploy.skip>${disable.deploy}</maven.deploy.skip>
    <deployAtEnd>${enable.deployAtEnd}</deployAtEnd>
</properties>
```

So effectively when I run `mvn deploy` on the parent pom, it will compile all the modules, not run install on anything, and then at the end deploy any module not having `