# maven deploying 3rd pom's without jar to nexus repository

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, nexus

When I want to deploy 3rd jars to my nexus 3 repository I use this command:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
-Dfile=<path-to-jar>
-DpomFile=<path-to-pom>
-DrepositoryId=<id-to-map-on-server-section-of-settings.xml>
-Durl=<url-of-the-repository-to-deploy>
```

but this command works only on jars with pom, and there is many artifacts that have only pom without jar, so i am looking for a way to deploy only pom without a jar file. My maven version is 3.3.9

Comment: did you tried without the *-Dfile* and is your pom have the packaging pom ?

Comment: my pom have the packaging pom, and when i remove the -Dfile i get an error - "the parameter file are missing or invalid"

Comment: seems like you can do -Dfile=pom.xml see http://stackoverflow.com/a/40259503/5070577

Comment: when I do -Dfile=pom.xml , I need to give the command 3 more parmaters: the groupId, artifactId and version. I solved this with adding -DpomFile=<path-to-pom> and -Dfile=<path-to-pom>, Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file
-DgroupId=com.xxx.xxx.xxxx
-DartifactId=xxxxx
-Dversion=x.x.x
-DgeneratePom=false
-DrepositoryId=nexus 
-Dpackaging=pom
-Dfile=D:/xxx/xxxxx-x.x.x.pom
-DpomFile=D:/xxx/xxxxx-x.x.x.pom
-Durl=http://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8081/repository/thirdparty
```

-Dfile, is mandatory for [Maven deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). Therefore you have to specify a file.

In this case, you can point the same pom file for both -DpomFile and -Dfile.

This works in Nexus OSS version 3.23.0-03 with Maven 3.5.2